# Why am I getting the wrong answer using pyTorch's cross-entropy?

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

I have a simple logit and target tensors and computing the cross entropy using Pytorch's `from torch.nn import functional as F` module.

```
>>> F.cross_entropy(torch.tensor([[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]]), torch.tensor([0]))

tensor(1.1891)
```

I'm getting 1.1891 as the answer. But according to the equation of cross_entropy loss, shouldn't the answer be

`-(1*ln(0.25) + 0*ln(0.5) + 0*ln(0.25) = -ln(0.25) = 1.386`?

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are missing how it is calculated. It is mentioned in documentation (related docs)

```
-torch.log(torch.softmax(a,dim=1))[0][0]
```

It calculates softmax of the entries first and then calculates cross-entropy.

In short

```
 F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(a), torch.tensor([0]))
```

Here is the linked [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) to which [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy.html) refers to

[image]